# innobackupex - after restoring a mysql backup the server can not start up

Tags: mysql, linux, innobackupex

After restoring a backup the mysql server can not start up..

```
quit without updating PID file
```

## backup command line

```
innobackupex --user=root --password=pass --databases="the_database" --stream=tar ./ 2> /var/log/innobackupex.log | gzip -c -1 > /var/bak/backup.tar.gz
```

## restore command lines

```
tar -izxf /var/bak/db/2013-11-16-2300_mysql.tar.gz -C /var/bak/db_import
innobackupex --defaults-file=/var/ini/my.cnf --use-memory=1G --apply-log /var/bak/db_import
service mysql stop
mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql-old
mkdir /var/lib/mysql
innobackupex --defaults-file=/var/ini/my.cnf --copy-back /var/bak/db_import
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
service mysql start
```

## /var/lib/mysql

```
innodb_index_stats.ibd
innodb_table_stats.ibd
slave_master_info.ibd
slave_relay_log_info.ibd
slave_worker_info.ibd
```

## error log

```
131121 14:08:12 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2013-11-21 14:08:13 0 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2013-11-21 14:08:13 0 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2013-11-21 14:08:13 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2013-11-21 14:08:13 14010 [Warning] Using pre 5.5 semantics to load error messages from /opt/mysql/server-5.6/share/english/.
2013-11-21 14:08:13 14010 [Warning] If this is not intended, refer to the documentation for valid usage of --lc-messages-dir and --language parameters.
2013-11-21 14:08:13 14010 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2013-11-21 14:08:13 14010 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2013-11-21 14:08:13 14010 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2013-11-21 14:08:13 14010 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2013-11-21 14:08:13 14010 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-11-21 14:08:13 14010 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2013-11-21 14:08:13 14010 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-11-21 14:08:13 14010 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2013-11-21 14:08:13 14010 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-11-21 14:08:13 14010 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2013-11-21 14:08:13 14010 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-11-21 14:08:13 14010 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-11-21 14:08:13 14010 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2013-11-21 14:08:14 14010 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2013-11-21 14:08:14 14010 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.14 started; log sequence number 56227635
2013-11-21 14:08:14 14010 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: fb44ff89-52ad-11e3-9dff-002185624b9b.
2013-11-21 14:08:15 14010 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2013-11-21 14:08:15 14010 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2013-11-21 14:08:15 14010 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2013-11-21 14:08:15 14010 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
131121 14:08:15 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have deleted (moved) the `/var/lib/mysql` folder, (`mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql-old`) which contains the `mysql` system database.

Restore this folder to its original location, then load your dump. This dump only contains data from your selected database.

The dump only restores data located in `/var/lib/mysql/[your_database]`. You should never touch files under `/var/lib/mysql/mysql`.

---

For completeness: with default settings, the `/var/lib/mysql` folder contains the following important system files, which should not be tampered with in a normal situation:

- `/var/lib/mysql/mysql/*`: the `mysql` system database
- `/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile*`: the redo log
- `/var/lib/mysql/ibdata*`: the default tablespace for `InnoDB` tables
- `/var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.*`: the binary log

Do not manipulate these files unless you exactly know what you are doing.

Comment: The backup is from the same server so it's the same version of mysql.. Have updated the question with the command line which backup the database

Comment: Yes, I just realised that it says `Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist` so it must be somthing else. Please check access rights (c.f. updates above).

Comment: Okay, I was completely off. I will write a new answer altogether.

Comment: have updated my question, with files in mysql dir.. this command line is runned before mysql startup `chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql`

Comment: ok, so I need to add mysql to the backup syntax `--databases="the_database mysql"` ??

Comment: On the contrary, I would suggest to never touch this database. Why do you move the `/var/lib/mysql` folder anyways? If you want to create a backup before importing the dump, then just create a new regular backup. You may want to include `mysql` in your backups, but the problem is that this database is tightly bound to a version of MySQL. This would make your backup impossible to use on another server. Perhaps you could backup `mysql` in a *separate* dump file.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care about original mysql privilege configurations (mysql database), you can run the install script, which will create the mysql database.

```
$ mysql_install_db
```

Answer (score 1):

You should backup all data, not only one database.

You need to use the `xtrabackup` command:

```
ex: xtrabackup --prepare --target-dir=/data/backups/mysql/
```

https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/xtrabackup_bin/preparing_the_backup.html

Comment: Links tend to change or go missing, could you explain some of the contents or quote it here?

Comment: Thanks! `prepare` is really needed, has some issues when I completely missed to do this.